# Exposing web API partially

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 Controllers in my Web API. I have to expose only one controller globally . And the other Controller should be accessed only within my network. I know one thing I can do is Authentication, which will prevent others from using my local services. But I need to prevent people even from seeing the local API.How to do this?ASP.Net Web API help page is displaying all my controllers which should not happen I should prevent it as well.

Note : Both the services were deployed at same place.

Comment: you need to exclude controller from help page , refre this : http://www.strathweb.com/2014/04/opt-opt-asp-net-web-api-help-page/

Comment: But still is will be accessible if someone knows the end point.